# What are the real life counterparts of the anime studios mentioned in episode 12 of Shirobako?

Tags: shirobako

In episode 12 of *Shirobako*, five major animation studios were listed:

> [image: a screenshot showing the logo for:]
>
> - スタジオカナン (Studio Canaan)
> - barmedéa
> - 武蔵野アニメーション (Musashino Animation)
> - The born
> - G.I.STAFF

I'm pretty sure "G.I.STAFF" is "J.C.STAFF".

What are the real-life counterparts of the other studios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer - I'm not sure about Studio Canaan.

- G.I. Staff → Production I.G (the "G" and "I" on the in-show logo are lifted directly from the actual logo), possibly with an admixture of J.C.Staff
- Barmedéa → Diomedéa (formerly known as Studio Barcelona; the logos are similar)
- The Born → probably Bones (the logos don't really match, but the president of The Born [Inami Masahiko] looks like the president of Bones [Minami Masahiko] - [comparison picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9HYW.png) courtesy [/u/TheVict on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/2pp0cb/spoilers_shirobako_episode_11_discussion/cmyvhgn))
- I doubt that Musashino Animation, being the focus of the show, is a parody of any existing studio. If it were, the obvious choice would be P.A. Works (which is the company producing Shirobako), but P.A. Works doesn't really map onto Musashino Animation well. P.A. Works is a lot more successful, for one.

Comment: Studio Canaan could be PA Works, they did do *Canaan* after all.

Comment: I'd think Musashino would map well to gonzo

Comment: @ton.yeung but Masushino has been in the industry for very long time, Gonzo on the other hand starts relatively recent. I was thinking this may relate to Mushi Production?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine theorizes Musashino is a parody of Shaft.

Up until *Madoka*, Shaft had not produced original work in years. Just like Musashino did with *Exodus!*, Shaft was the same with *Madoka*. But that's according to him.

Answer (score 0):

Musashino Animation is most likely Mushi Production.

Masato Marukawa, the owner of MusAni, is based on real-life producer and animator Masao Maruyama, who did animation work as MushiPro.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure Musashino Animation is [Tatsunoko Production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatsunoko_Production).

From the anime, there is a poster parodying the anime *The Adventures of Hutch the Honeybee* which is the anime produced by Tatsunoko. Tatsunoko itself resides in Musashino, Tokyo.